# Why do I get "file is not of required architecture" installing Ruby 1.9.3 using RVM on Mac OSX 10.6?

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to install Ruby 1.9.3 on Mac OSX 10.6. I have 10.8.7 installed fine already. There are already a bunch of these topics on StackOverflow, but their fixes haven't been working.
Here's what the terminal prints out:

```
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/cavan/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #fetching 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/cavan/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring 
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #compiling 
Error running 'make ', please read /Users/cavan/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

And here's the error part of the log it's requesting:

```
linking shared-object digest/md5.bundle
compiling rmd160init.c
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file is not of required architecture
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin10.7.0/digest/md5.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/md5/all] Error 2
make[1]: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
compiling rmd160ossl.c
installing default rmd160 libraries
linking shared-object digest/rmd160.bundle
ld: in /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib, file is not of required architecture
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [../../../.ext/x86_64-darwin10.7.0/digest/rmd160.bundle] Error 1
make[1]: *** [ext/digest/rmd160/all] Error 2
make: *** [build-ext] Error 2
```

I think it has to do with the "file is not of required architecture message." My computer came with 10.6 and is 64-bit.

Comment: What's the output of `file /usr/local/lib/libz.1.dylib`?

Comment: It's not opening or running. "An unexpected error occurred (error code -43)." I think this means theres a problem with xcode.

Comment: The problem is definitely that file. You should find out what installed it (not Xcode I think, since it's not on my machine with latest Xcode), and probably just remove it. Ruby doesn't need it to compile as it already comes with OS X AFAIK.

Comment: It's highly likely this is a 32-bit library when you need 64.  This is zlib, which is used for compression.  You need to get the 64-bit version.  If you use MacPorts and upgraded from Leopard to Snow Leopard, there is a known issue, which can be fixed by re-installing MacPorts.  If not, you could try getting zlib sources and building/installing those before ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have issues with compiling different libraries, I have already solved those issues while building RailsInstaller for OSX => http://railsinstaller.org/